# Is std::string::npos == -1 always true?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer

The title is relatively self explanatory.  I recognize the similarity to other answers, but all of those have different arrangements of operators (and therefore different casting rules).  So I require an answer that clarifies this particular case.

If someone could point out the section of the standard that explains this, I will gladly vote up and accept the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*NO*, it is not always true. It is however a bit more complicated than it seems at first glance:

In the beginning, let us see what `std::string` is (21.3/1):

> The header `<string>` defines the `basic_string` class template for manipulating varying-length sequences
> of char-like objects and four typedefs, `string`, `u16string`, `u32string`, and `wstring`, that name the specializations
> `basic_string<char>`, `basic_string<char16_t>`, `basic_string<char32_t>`, and `basic_string<wchar_t>`, respectively.

Start out with 21.4/5:

> ```
> template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
> ```

```
    class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string {
    typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type;
    static const size_type npos = -1;
// [other members omitted]
};
```

Note that while `npos` is initialized with `-1`, its type depends on `Allocator::size_type`, which means that without further knowledge, we cannot simply assume that `string::npos == -1` will even compile.

Now, as `string` uses the default allocator (the template parameter has the default value in the typedef provided by the standard library after all), let us check 20.6.9:

> ```
> typedef size_t size_type;
> ```

Now, we can essentially rewrite the question as: `size_t(-1) == -1`. What happens now depends on the types of the subexpressions: The left hand side obviously has type `size_t`, while the right hand side is an integer literal, which has type `int`, when written like this (without further qualifiers).

The result is `true` if `size_t` is at least as large as `int` (for standards fanatics: Has a larger or equal integer conversion rank as defined in 4.13). Otherwise, the *left hand side* will get promoted to `int`, causing a comparision like `0xFFFF == -1` (for `size_t` being `uint16_t` and `int` having 32 bit), which is `false`.

Note that while 16 bit systems themselves are not very common anymore (except for some remnants in very small form factors), `int` is not restricted to 32 bit by the standard. A compiler targetting x86_64 with `64` bit `size_t` and 128 bit `int` would be technically compliant.

All quotes are from the C++11 standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011).

Comment: As a follow up question, would first converting the type of the left hand side to a signed type cause the expression to be guaranteed? For example: `(signed size_t) std::string::npos == -1`

Comment: @randomusername That conversion results in undefined behaviour, as the value of `npos` is to large. Just do the following: `std::string::npos == std::string::size_type(-1)` and you are fine.

Answer (score 5):

There is a loophole for the question you literally asked.

If `int` has (strictly) greater integer conversion rank than `string::size_type` and `int` can store the full range of values of `string::size_type`, then `string::npos == -1` will be false, as both arguments will get promoted to `int`, rather than being promoted to `string::size_type`.

An environment where this happens would be rather unusual.

This comes from the *usual arithmetic conversions*:

> ...
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
>   rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall
>   be converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the
>   type of the operand with signed integer type.

Comment: So are you suggesting that `string::size_type` would not be sign extended in the cast to `int`?

Comment: @randomusername: `string::size_type` is unsigned, so there is no sign bit to extend; the conversion preserves the value, and so it will get converted into a nonnegative `int`. Note that `npos` is a positive value: in fact, the largest value that can be stored in `string::size_type`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is defined as `-1`

[N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) § 21.4 / 5 provides the class template for `std::basic_string` which includes the line

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```